# Numerical method for solving Irrational Equation

Tags: numerical-methods

How to solve the following equation:

> $x \arcsin(x^2) + 2\sqrt{1-x^2}\arcsin(x) = 2x   $

I think it is hard. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)

Comment: $x=0$ $ { } $ $ { } $ $ { } $

Comment: @draks $x=0$ is only one of the solutions. There are more.

Comment: I checked that this has 3 roots. $x=0$ is easy to see, how about 2 other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only three roots, in $\{-u,0,u\}$, with $u$ pretty close to $1$. By convexity, the Newton method with starting point $x_0=\pm 1$ has quadratic convergence.

Comment: How can you get this has only three roots?